# log4j not printing long log messages

Tags: java, logging, log4j

While going through the log files I found that long log messages are printed partially in log file.

we are using following ConversionPattern:

```
%d{ss:SSS} %-5p [%X{moduleName}] [%t] [%X{sessionId}] %c{2} %m%n
```

log4j version: 1.2.17

I found this issue on production log file, on local machine it works correctly(prints whole log message).

we want to print the whole log message. 
is it specific to platform?

can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: On which platform is it running? Does this go into a fileappender? Does the message contain line breaks?

Comment: Hi Fildor, we are using Linux server at production.
Yes we have configured fileappender in log4j, message doesn't contains any line break.

Comment: About how long are those messages? Are they all cut at the same length?

Comment: It is about 2000 characters long.

Comment: No they are not cut at the same length.

Comment: Not sure if there is a max length in log 4j for messages. But anyway, 2000 seems very verbose to me. I'd try reducing verbosity or/and splitting those messages into smaller ones. Still odd why it is different on Linux though ...

Comment: Can you post am example? Best one from your Dev system and one from production to compare them.

Comment: Sorry Fildor, It has transaction data :-)

Comment: Could it be something in the string data? Like an Ansi-NULL ?